# VLAN for VoIP alone

Tags: vlan, packet-tracer

[image]

In the topology above, I want to create a single VLAN which houses the router and the VoIP phones alone. All other devices should be excluded from this VLAN.
I don’t want to use voice VLAN, just normal VLAN.
What is the configuration?

Comment: Since you're not sharing the phone links, simply create a VLAN on all switches, use trunks in between switches and access ports towards the phones and the router.

Comment: @Zac67 You mean I should create a VLAN on the switch that connects the access switches as well?

Comment: @Paa The VLAN ID needs to exist on any switch where a phone is present or any switch where phone traffic will pass through it.  So, if the phone traffic is on switch 1 but has to pass through switch 2 to get to the router/firewall to get to the internet, you would need to also have the same voice VLAN on switch 2 even though the phones aren’t directly connected to it.

Comment: @Jesse P. 
So would I trunk the links on the switch that connects the other switches and add them to the VLAN as well?

Comment: @Paa Correct. Trunks between the switches (to carry multiple VLAN IDs), add the VLAN ID to the VLAN database on each switch as needed. Assign the VLAN to each of the phones. Since you aren’t using the pass-through ports on the phones for the workstations, you don’t need to use `switchport voice vlan <id>`, just use `switchport access vlan <id>`.  The command `switchport voice vlan` is for when you need to have separate data and voice traffic on the same switch port, using different VLAN IDs and potentially using QoS. Since you don’t (in your diagram),that’s not necessary.

Comment: @Jesse P. 
It still does not work. I get the error message “received bpdu with inconsistent peer VLAN id.” On the ports on the access switches that the phones connect to. Can you please help with a working configuration.

Comment: @Paa No. You need to provide sanitized configs for your switches so we can help figure out where you went wrong.  We can’t just guess and we are not here to build entire switch configs for you.